# Is there a way to import a .pyo file in an ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-import

During interactive IPython notebook sessions, that usually only require normal imports, sometimes there is a need to import an occasional .pyo file.

Is there any IPython magic or a python API to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imports .pyo files only if run with with `-O` option:

```
python -O
```

Starting the whole IPyhon Notebook with this option does seem to work. At least I did not get to work.

As this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue12982) points out, a workaround would be to rename the .pyo file into a .pyc file. Than Python will import it:

> Actually it's a lot easier than that, although it is very much a hack: just rename the .pyo files to .pyc, and python without -O will happily import them.  Since the optimization happens when the bytecode is written, this does what you want.
>
> R. David Murray (r.david.murray)